# Induced current by demagnetization

Tags: specific-reference, electromagnetic-induction, ferromagnetism

Take a ferromagnetic conductor (with a non-zero $\vec{M}$ magnetization, regardless of $\vec{B}$). It is known that ferromagnetic materials can be partially demagnetized by a mechanical shock (for exemple, a magnet can be damaged if dropped). Then, the $\vec{B}$-field created by $\vec{M}$ should drop quickly after such a shock, and hence induce an electric field by $\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E} = -\partial\vec{B}/\partial t$, and thus a current in the material.

Am I right, and were such currents observed experimentally ?

Comment: Why do you think you might be wrong?

Comment: I don't think I'm wrong, I'm just curious about an eventual observation. Did not found any paper on the subject, maybe I haven't searched enough. Maybe someone actually did the experiment as a teacher/student.

Comment: If you are looking for a paper on this topic, you should use the *specific reference* tag.

Comment: one possibility is [Electromagnetic Field Formed by Shock Compression of a Conducting Magnetic](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/B:CESW.0000007685.61749.a9)

Comment: @sammy-gerbil Looks interesting ! And thanks for the advice.